# How to read opendocument spreadsheet .ods file from SSIS

Tags: file, ssis, ods

I need to create a package in ssis that reads data from opendocument spreadsheet (ODS).
Columns in ODS file are dynamic. For example, for this month source file (.ODS) will arrive with columns like
T1,T2,T3

Next Month, Source file (.ODS) will arrive with columns like

T2,T3,T4

Please help how I can do this in SSIS.